# Java Regular Expression not working, same pattern works on online website

Tags: java, regex

**Problem**

I am trying to to extract words from input

```
Pacific Gas & Electric (PG&E), San Diego Gas & Electric (SDG&E), Salt River Project (SRP), Southern California Edison (SCE)
```

I tried doing that online and my pattern `(\w\s?&?\s?\(?\)?)` [seems to work](http://rubular.com/r/RZnUO7qhz9).

But when I write my Java program, it is not finding it

```
private static void findWords() {
    final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\w\\s?&?\\s?\\(?\\)?)");
    final String INPUT = "Pacific Gas & Electric (PG&E), San Diego Gas & Electric (SDG&E), Salt River Project (SRP), Southern California Edison (SCE)";

    final Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(INPUT);
    System.out.println(matcher.matches());
}
```

It returns `False`

**Question**

1. Why is there a mismatch, seems like my understanding is poor here
2. How can I get the words out as groups, meaning `Pacific Gas & Electric (PG&E)` as match group1 and so on

Comment: FYI: The differences between the [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) functions ([`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()), [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()), and [`lookingAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)) are listed under "Flavor-Specific Information" in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496).

Answer (score 4):

If you use `Matcher#find()` method instead of `Matcher#matches()` method, you'll get `true` as outcome. The reason being, the `matches()` method assumes implicit anchors - carat (`^`) and dollar (`$`) at the ends. So it would match the entire string with the regex. If that is not the case, it will return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to re-evaluate the output you're getting from rubular.

from [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

> The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.

What you have there in rubular finds a bunch of matches because just about every character is a match.

nowhere in your rubular result will it tell you that the entire string is a match though.  I'd re-evaluate the results you're seeing there.

---

and a regular expression to match words is extremely simple

you can use

```
\b\S*\b
```

http://rubular.com/r/ljYs1xO1Qh

or simply

```
\S*
```

http://rubular.com/r/xgEuGse1lc

depending on your needs

Answer (score 2):

`Matcher#matches` returns only true if the whole string matches the regular expression.

As you can see in your online matcher, your regex matches not the whole string but a single character (sometimes a bit more). So your regex matches "P" and "a" and "c" and "i" and so on. You should fix your regex first and then use `Matcher#find()` and `Matcher#group()` to get the matching groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the matches out of your string, here this is you can try:

```
final String INPUT = "Pacific Gas & Electric (PG&E), San Diego Gas & Electric (SDG&E), Salt River Project (SRP), Southern California Edison (SCE)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\([^)]+\\))(?:,\\s*|$)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(INPUT);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Alternately, you can do `INPUT.split("\\s*,\\s*");` if the names doesn't contain any comma inside.

Now come to the question `Why is there a mismatch, seems like my understanding is poor here`: Because the `matches()` of String class perform matching over the whole string.